# How to rewrite into a indirect question

Tags: questions

> “I never know," Harry called to Hagrid over the noise of the cart,
>   "what's the difference between a stalagmite and a stalactite?" (Harry
>   Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

There comes direct question after ‘I never know’. If it were indirect question, would it be ‘I never know what the difference between a stalagmite and stalactite is.’?

Comment: *Indirect question* is a term used with two meanings.  SF has given you an answer addressing one meaning of the term; I've assumed you meant the other and given you a question addressing that meaning instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's right.  The quote introduces a direct question with *I never know*:

> I never know, what's the difference between a stalagmite and a stalactite?

You've turned it into an indirect question (a *wh*-relative clause):

> I never know [ what the difference between a stalagmite and stalactite is. ]

The main difference is that the indirect question doesn't take the form of a question grammatically, so it doesn't undergo subject-auxiliary inversion, and it ends with a period rather than a question mark.  The other difference is that the original sentence, containing a direct question, can contain a comma between the matrix verb and its complement; see [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/10850/230) for a description of that structure.

Answer (score 1):

An indirect question is a request for answer, phrased as a question.

So, in this case it would be:

> "Could you tell me what the difference between stalagmite and a stalactite is?"
>
> "Hagrid, do you know the difference between a stalagmite and a stalactite?

This is opposed to a direct question:

> "Hagrid, what is the difference between stalagmite and a stalactite?"

In your situation, calling your quote an indirect question would be strecthing it: From grammatical point of view, your quote is not a question at all. It's a statement used in function of question.

Comment: Does this - "I never know what the difference between a stalagmite and stalactite is" - make sense in itself?

Comment: @Listenever: Yes, but grammatically it's a statement: Harry informs Hagrid about his own lack of knowledge. He does not request to change that situation. It could be just as well a reply to Hagrid asking: "Is this a stalactite or a stalagmite?"