# "I wonder what was the difficulty" vs "I wonder what the difficulty was."

Tags: grammar

"I wonder what the difficulty was." vs "I wonder what was the difficulty."

"I wonder when was the toughest time." vs "I wonder when the toughest time was."

I know that "I wonder what they are doing" is correct but "I wonder what are they doing" is ungrammatical. But I'm so confused with the sentences like above. Help :(

Comment: "I wonder what are they doing" is not ungrammatical and is quite common.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rewrite into a indirect question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11459/how-to-rewrite-into-a-indirect-question)

Comment: @Chenmunka Disagree. That's ungrammatical to me. At the very least it needs a comma and a question mark: "I wonder, what are they doing?"

Comment: True, it needs punctuation if written.  But only Victor Borge speaks commas.

Comment: @Chenmunka as a statement, "I wonder what are they doing" is common and incorrect.  Non-native speakers often invert subject and verb in a subordinate clause when the subordinating conjunction is a word such as "where" or "how" that can also serve as an interrogative pronoun. Only Victor Borge speaks commas audibly, but everyone speaks question marks through intonation.

Answer (score 1):

Inverting the subject and the auxiliary verb shows that we're asking a question. If we're not asking a question, we must leave them in the normal subject-auxiliary order.

With wh-clauses, if the subject and auxiliary are inverted, it's a complete question sentence, but if they're not inverted, it's just a noun phrase representing that information.

> What is your name? (*complete question sentence*)
>
> what your name is (*noun phrase; not a sentence*)

Take this sentence:

> I know **something**.

There, "something" is clearly a noun phrase, the direct object of "know". The word "something" can be replaced with a wh-clause (without inversion):

> I know **what the difficulty was**.

There is no question here at all. This is a statement about something the speaker knows. The phrase "what the difficulty was" represents that information.

In your example sentences, "wonder" does the same job as "know". It introduces a direct object *without asking any question*. The only difference is that rather than the speaker claiming to **know** something, the speaker is claiming to **wonder about** something. So it's not a question at all, just a statement.

It's common to use a statement like, "I wonder what the difficulty was" as a way of indirectly asking a question, but the sentence itself is not a question grammatically, so the subject and auxiliary verb cannot be inverted.